# Multiple Producer / One Consumer Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a ServerClass which spawns new threads.

Each thread is given a block of data for processing. Each thread process 'x' chunk of data and return some value to the ServerClass. 
ServerClass averages collected values and pass this to the threads. And threads resumes work using the averaged values.
Same process is repeated until the whole data is processed by the threads.

I wrote this and I get different outputs each time I execute it.
Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong.

```
ServerClass

public synchronized void put(double[] weight)
{

        //System.out.println(Counter);      

        weights.add(weight);

        if(Counter+1 == NoOfThreads)

        {           

            averageWeights();

            notifyAll();

            Counter =0;

        } else

            try {

                Counter++;

                wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

        }

}

Threads Class

refer // ServerClass Reference

updatedweights // Averaged Value

int slots = data.size() / batchCount;

            for(int i=0; i<slots;i++)

            {

                double[] p = Algo(data,i*batchCount, (i+1)*batchCount, ServerClass.stepSize, labelIndex, refer.updatedweights);

                refer.put(p);

            }
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing with your code? Explain that

Comment: Read up on cyclic barriers, they will be of good use to you here.

Comment: @Jayamohan : I am getting different `updatedweights` variable even after passing the same input.
I want to ask, can I call `wait()` inside a `synchronized` method? Will it prevent other threads to execute the method ( in my case `put()` ).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void put(double[] weight, Threads t)
{
     updatingWVector(weight);
        if(checkCondition())
        {            
            averageWeights();               
            Counter =0;
            synchronized(lock) {
                //System.out.println(t.getId());
                  lock.notifyAll();
            }
        } else
        {

                try {
                    updateCounter();
                    synchronized(lock) {
                        System.out.println(t.getId());
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Where `lock` is 
`private final Object lock = new Object();`
Rest all the methods in the code are in `synchronized` block.